# Ruby on Rails with Figaro and Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm using localhost right now and installed the Figaro gem to help me test using Paperclip with my S3 bucket. When I try to upload something, I get this message:

```
missing required :bucket option
```

In development.rb I inserted the following code:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
storage: :s3,
s3_credentials: {
  bucket: :ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
  access_key_id: :ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
  secret_access_key: :ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
}
```

And then I placed the following code in the Figaro-generated application.yml file:

```
development:
  AWS_BUCKET: (the actual name of my bucket)
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: (the actual access key)
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: (etc)
```

I will say that when I declare what the bucket is directly into the model I'm using for this, it does seem to work (a new folder is generated in my bucket) but the image never actually appears in the destination (perhaps a separate issue or perhaps not).

I know I am missing something obvious here, I'm probably not doing something right. Using Rails v4 with aws-sdk v1.34 and Figaro v0.7.0. Thanks to anyone who can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is just a syntax typo.  ENV is a variable; it's a hash and not a symbol.  Just remove the `:` from in front of `ENV`.  It should be:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
storage: :s3,
  s3_credentials: {
    bucket: ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
    access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
}
```

Comment: Yep, that was it. Hmm, the file is still not ending up in the bucket though (no error message in browser). The folder is created but no file. Not sure what's going on there. Will look at this tomorrow and check this as the answer, possibly make a new question if I cannot solve.

Answer (score 1):

Further to your comment, this is live code which is 100% working for us right now:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
    storage: :s3,
    s3_host_name: 's3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com',
    s3_credentials: {
      access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    },
    bucket: ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']
}
```

Also make sure you restart your rails server each time you change these details. Reason being the config files are loaded at initialization, and maintained for the server's session

Comment: Thanks much. I put in the host name for good measure but I think my missing file had more to do with the fact that I needed to tweak my :path AND I needed to hard refresh my S3 page more than what I was doing.